# Will Air pressure sensor (that is closing one end of a hollow tube) give same reading irrespective of length of tube given same pressure applied?

Tags: pressure

Using an Air Pressure sensor. I measured the Air pressure applied to a hollow tube. The tube is closed at one end by the Sensor, so no air can cross the tube. I applied Air pressure into it and got a value reading from the sensor. When applying the same pressure, but this time using a slightly longer tube, I got the same reading on the sensor.

I was wondering, if the length of the tube has any role...? so, that if same pressure is applied then whether I take a long or short or a very very long tube, the sensor would read the same reading for both longer and shorter tube. As per my understanding, there should not be any difference but still wanted to confirm if anyone can help with scientific proof/law on what is the reality.

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal case, you are correct. Remember that pressure is force over area, P=F/A. You might get confused in thinking that a longer cylinder has more surface area, but one has to be careful here. Since pressure acts equally in all directions (on average) the pressure you apply will always be the pressure read out on the other end.
Consider this: How do you control how much pressure is being applied? assuming you are using some kind of piston or diaphragm, that device must also have some kind of sensor in it telling you how much pressure is being applied. Because of the aforementioned principle, you should always read the same pressure on other end, or in fact anywhere in the tube after sufficient time has passed.

It is worth noting that for a very long tube it could take considerable time to get the same pressure reading on the far end, since it takes time for the pressure wave to propagate. In most lab scale settings though, this time should be negligible.